# Order RSS feed 301 redirecting

Tags: redirect, rss

When I try visiting the New Order RSS feed, it returns a 301 redirect (url i'm trying is http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/rss/order/new/ - the redirect sends me straight back the root URL of the store http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/nz/

I've got the same thing happening with MageMonkey too (this uses a /monkey/ URL).

The .htaccess i'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Please add more info. Where are you redirected to for example, what is the base url you've stated in the backend of your shop etc. This is too little to go on

Comment: Did you try calling `http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/nz/rss/order/new/` ?

Comment: Ah - that's sorted it.

Comment: Is there any way to configure the feed link URL that shows at the top of the Orders page? It points to the /rss rather than /nz/rss

Comment: Did you turn on `Add Store Code to Urls` under `System > Configuration > Web`? And is the Base URL `http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/`?

Comment: No - it causes issues over the site.

Comment: Please state the settings you have under the sys/conf web section

Comment: Did you manage to get your issue resolved?

Comment: Yep - had to add the store code to the URL, and i've updated the redirect to redirect the standard link to a store code URL. So `http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/rss/order/new/` will redirect to `http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/nz/rss/order/new/` and show the RSS page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the store code to the URL, and i've updated the redirect to redirect the standard link to a store code URL. So `http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/rss/order/new/` will redirect to `http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/nz/rss/order/new/` and show the RSS page.

Answer (score 1):

When enabling `Add Store Code to Urls` under `System > Configuration` the Admin section might have some issues with that.

I'd advice to turn the option off on the `Default Config` level only enabling it for the website levels. This way you should be able to call the RSS feed using just the base URL

`http://{SITE_NAME}.dev/rss/order/new/`